# "Of her brother's" or "of her brother"?

Tags: possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

Is there a difference in whether *brother* is explicitly possessive in sentences like this?

> - A friend of her brother's called
> - A friend of her brother called

Perhaps both are correct; do they have a subtle (or not-so-subtle) difference?

Comment: I think the proper usages here are "A friend of her brother" and "Her brother's friend". I have no explanation for this (hence not an answer). But it makes sense to me this way.

Comment: I don't think this particular usage has been answered. The referenced duplicate is unanswered and is also marked duplicate, and the referenced question from there pertains to a pronoun.